# Generating an excel file in mason from a bytebuffer

Tags: excel, mason

I have some mason code that calls my backend service, which returns the bytebuffer representation of the excel workbook I wish to generate. In writing the excel file, I end up with an excel file full of gibberish (presumably the bytebuffer itself). This is how I'm writing out the file (where $response is the bytebuffer returned by my backend service):

```
$m->clear_buffer();
setHeader('content-type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
setHeader('Content-Disposition', attachment; filename="packlist.xlsx");
WPHTTPResponse::write($response);
$m->abort();
```

I know my function is being called and that it is returning an object, but I don't know where it is going wrong in writing. Am I missing a step or did I write something incorrectly? Any ideas?

Much appreciated